# Sending information to server, java.net.SocketException: socket failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

Tags: java, android, sockets, exception

I get the error

> java.net.SocketException: socket failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

This is my method to post data to the server

```
public void postData(String stuff){
    //Create a new HTTPClient and Post Header
    URL url;
    HttpURLConnection con = null;
    status.setText("In post");
    try{
        url = new URL("http://myaddress/gpsin");
        con = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        con.setDoOutput(true);
        con.setRequestMethod("POST");
        con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8");
        con.connect();

        //Send Request
        DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
        wr.writeBytes((stuff));
        wr.flush();
        wr.close();

        InputStream is;
        int response = con.getResponseCode();
        if(response >= 200 && response<= 399){
            //return success
            status.setText("Success!");
        }else{
            //return fail
            status.setText("Fail");
        }
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        status.setText("In catch");
    }finally{
        if(con!=null)con.disconnect();
    }
}
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.jake.locationapp">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

LogCat:

```
09-09 12:43:33.308 11819-11819/com.jake.locationapp W/System.err: java.net.SocketException: socket failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
09-09 12:43:33.308 11819-11819/com.jake.locationapp W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.socket(IoBridge.java:623)
09-09 12:43:33.308 11819-11819/com.jake.locationapp W/System.err:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.create(PlainSocketImpl.java:198)
09-09 12:43:33.308 11819-11819/com.jake.locationapp W/System.err:     at java.net.Socket.checkOpenAndCreate(Socket.java:689)
09-09 12:43:33.308 11819-11819/com.jake.locationapp W/System.err:     at java.net.Socket.setSoTimeout(Socket.java:543)
09-09 12:43:33.308 11819-11819/com.jake.locationapp W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:158)
09-09 12:43:33.308 11819-11819/com.jake.locationapp W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:174)
09-09 12:43:33.308 11819-11819/com.jake.locationapp W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:316)
09-09 12:43:33.308 11819-11819/com.jake.locationapp W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:249)
09-09 12:43:33.308 11819-11819/com.jake.locationapp W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:397)
09-09 12:43:33.308 11819-11819/com.jake.locationapp W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:118)
09-09 12:43:33.308 11819-11819/com.jake.locationapp W/System.err:     at com.jake.locationapp.MainActivity.postData(MainActivity.java:84)
09-09 12:43:33.308 11819-11819/com.jake.locationapp W/System.err:     at com.jake.locationapp.MainActivity$MyLocationListener.onLocationChanged(MainActivity.java:197)
09-09 12:43:33.308 11819-11819/com.jake.locationapp W/System.err:     at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport._handleMessage(LocationManager.java:285)
09-09 12:43:33.308 11819-11819/com.jake.locationapp W/System.err:     at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport.access$000(LocationManager.java:214)
09-09 12:43:33.308 11819-11819/com.jake.locationapp W/System.err:     at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport$1.handleMessage(LocationManager.java:230)
09-09 12:43:33.308 11819-11819/com.jake.locationapp W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
09-09 12:43:33.308 11819-11819/com.jake.locationapp W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
09-09 12:43:33.308 11819-11819/com.jake.locationapp W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5430)
09-09 12:43:33.308 11819-11819/com.jake.locationapp W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
09-09 12:43:33.308 11819-11819/com.jake.locationapp W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
09-09 12:43:33.308 11819-11819/com.jake.locationapp W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:913)
09-09 12:43:33.308 11819-11819/com.jake.locationapp W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:706)
09-09 12:43:33.308 11819-11819/com.jake.locationapp W/System.err: Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: socket failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
09-09 12:43:33.308 11819-11819/com.jake.locationapp W/System.err:     at libcore.io.Posix.socket(Native Method)
09-09 12:43:33.308 11819-11819/com.jake.locationapp W/System.err:     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.socket(BlockGuardOs.java:282)
09-09 12:43:33.308 11819-11819/com.jake.locationapp W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.socket(IoBridge.java:608)
09-09 12:43:33.308 11819-11819/com.jake.locationapp W/System.err:   ... 21 more
```

I've done a decent amount of googling, but all I could find was people misplacing the permissions line in the Manifest

Comment: Try proceeding without calling `.connect()`.  The docs are a bit confusing in this regard as it tells you that the returned `URLConnection` is not connected on creation, but the `HttpURLConnection` samples never show an actual call to `.connect()`.  It could be that you are already connected and your subsequent call to `.connect()` is attempting to make a connection when one is already done, causing a strange permission problem behind the scenes.

Comment: Surely there is a permission for networking itself? This is a socket creation error, and so far nothing to do with Internet.

Comment: I'm having a hard time believing in this. Why would `setSoTimeout()` be called before the underlying socket FD was created? and/or why would it create another socket FD? It appears to be a bug in Android: either `Socket.setSoTImeout()` or `HttpURLConnection.connect()` is doing something very odd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Try proceeding without calling .connect(). The docs are a bit confusing in this regard as it tells you that the returned URLConnection is not connected on creation, but the HttpURLConnection samples never show an actual call to .connect(). It could be that you are already connected and your subsequent call to .connect() is attempting to make a connection when one is already done, causing a strange permission problem behind the scenes. – Larry Schiefer

This worked!